# How would I sort these directory names numerically?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, sort

I'm aware that I can somehow sort this output numerically (so cpu1/ follows cpu0/) ... I could probably get something to work eventually by splitting up the string various ways with awk, but is there an "easy" way that would be somewhat reusable in the future in other scripts?

```
> for i in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq; do echo -n "$i: "; cat $i; done
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 2395000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu16/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu17/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu18/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu19/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu20/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "version sort" seems to work fine with this.

```
for i in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq; 
   do echo -n "$i: "; cat $i; done | sort -V
```

Comment: It worked on my Debian box

Comment: Just an addendum...sort on my Ubuntu 8.04 server doesn't have that option...it's there on my RHEL6 boxes though.

Answer (score 2):

This should work with most *sort* implementations:

```
 ... | sort -t/ -k6.4n
```

Trying to set an example (cannot find cpufreq on the systems I have access to ...):

input file

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 2395000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu16/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu17/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu18/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu19/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu20/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
```

output:

```
zsh-4.3.12[t]% sort -t/ -k6.4n infile
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 2395000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu16/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu17/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu18/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu19/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu20/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: 1064000
```

Comment: That doesn't work with my example on either RHEL 6.1 or Ubuntu 8.04.

Comment: Hi @twblamer, I've just added an example in my post. Could you please post the output that you get?

Comment: False alarm...I was using different input data than what I initially posted. It's working now...sorry.