# How to sort the string which combined with string + numeric using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, sort

This is the data what I want to sort. But `sort` treats the numeric to string, the data it no sorted as I expected.

> /home/files/profile1
>   /home/files/profile10
>   /home/files/profile11
>   /home/files/profile12
>   /home/files/profile14
>   /home/files/profile15
>   /home/files/profile16
>   /home/files/profile2
>   /home/files/profile3
>   /home/files/profile4
>   /home/files/profile5
>   /home/files/profile6
>   /home/files/profile7
>   /home/files/profile8
>   /home/files/profile9

I want to sort this to,

> /home/files/profile1
>   /home/files/profile2
>   /home/files/profile3
>   /home/files/profile4
>   /home/files/profile5
>   /home/files/profile6
>   /home/files/profile7
>   /home/files/profile8
>   /home/files/profile9
>   /home/files/profile10
>   /home/files/profile11
>   /home/files/profile12
>   /home/files/profile14
>   /home/files/profile15
>   /home/files/profile16

Is there a good way by bash script? I can't use ruby or python script in here.

Comment: try using "sort -nd"

Comment: @bobah, "sort: options `-dn' are incompatible"

Comment: `sort -V` would do.

Comment: @Thor. your comment would make a good answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088370/sort-numerically

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a temporary sentinel character to delimit the number:

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\)/;\1/' log | sort -n -t\; -k2,2 | tr -d ';'
```

Here, the sentinel character is ';' - it must not be part of any filename you want to sort - but you can exchange the ';' with any character you like. You have to change the `sed`, `sort` and `tr` part then accordingly.

The pipe works as follows: The `sed` command inserts the sentinel before any number, the `sort` command interprets the sentinel as field delimiter, sorts with the second field as numeric sort key and the `tr` command removes the sentinel again.

And `log` denotes the input file - you can also pipe your input into `sed`.

Comment: I like the way you resolved the problem :)

Answer (score 46):

This is very similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23372/how-would-i-sort-these-directory-names-numerically). The trouble is that you have an alphanumeric field that you are sorting on, and `-n` doesn't treat that sensibly, however version sort (`-V`) does. Thus use:

```
sort -V
```

Note that this feature is currently supported by the GNU, FreeBSD and OpenBSD sort implementations.

Comment: Do you know how portable is this? This option doesn't seem to be part of the POSIX spec.

Comment: @ErnestA: You are right, this is GNU sort specific solution. Added a note.

Comment: @ErnestA: I looks like FreeBSD and OpenBSD have added this feature.

Comment: And it doesn't work if the numbers have different prefixes.

Comment: To any readers: Note that this is a CAPITAL V! Use `sort -V` not `sort -v`. It's hard to tell at first glance.

Answer (score 7):

If all your file names have the same prefix before the final numeric part, ignore it when sorting:

```
sort -k 1.20n
```

(20 is the position of the first digit. It's one plus the length of `/home/files/profile`.)

If you have several different non-numeric parts, [insert a sentinel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41655/how-to-sort-the-string-which-combined-with-string-numeric-using-bash-script/41656#41656).